# How can I indent to the level of an open parenthesis?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, indentation

I am using MS Visual Studio 2012 to write C# applications.  If a function has many arguments, I sometimes like to have one argument per line:

```
    public void BuildFile(string destinationFolderName,
                          string namespaceName,
                          string className,
                          string fullTableName,
                          string baseTableName, 
                          List<SimpleADONetField> fields)
```

But the automatic formatting applied by VS 2012 only gives me a single level of indentation more than the current block.  So, if I put my cursor at the end of the first line, the automactic indenting is one indentation beyond "public".  Is there an add-in or any such tool available that will indent the line following an open parenthesis to one space more than the location of the parenthesis?  If not, how would I go about writing one?

Thanks very much!

Comment: If I have to break it up like that, I prefer to place each argument on it's own line, indented once (i.e. `string destinationFolderName` below `BuildFile(` and indented once). IIRC I think that's what StyleCop recommends by default as well.

Comment: I think you'll need to wait for the Elastic Tabstops plugin to be completed for this. However, any method with that many parameters urgently needs a redesign. My preference when indenting is the pure VS standard, because blocks of parameters at different depths look rather awful to me.

Comment: Unrelated, but methods with +5 parameters are a bad design. You should create a proper data model to store your data, and pass an instance of that to the method, which is a much more maintainable, scalable, cleaner approach.

Comment: You can probably do that with resharper. But, don't. It's really best of you indent just one tab more that the line before.

Answer (score 1):

I like your styling. Unfortunately there is no option in the C# Formatting section of Visual Studio to do that.

The best one could do is to place each of the variables on their own line as you have it shown above. Then manually adjust the spacing by holding down the alt key while also holding down the left mouse button selection and drag a vertical line from the second variable to the last. Letting go of the key and mouse then hit the space bar to *in unison* move the variables to their ultimate position.

Comment: +1 for not accusing the OP of bad design. Everyone deals with fitting wide function declarations and calls within the available screen real estate.